# One line bash Script to Edit File (not create a new one)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, edit

I'm a newbie at bash script and I'm trying to write a bash script to edit a configuration file. i want to remove " foo" from the file.

Using the code

```
echo
sed -e "s/ foo//" ./test > ./test2
```

will create a new file with the content i want. But if i try to edit the same file using this

```
echo
sed -e "s/ foo//" ./test > ./test
```

the file will just become empty. Is this not the way? how can i simply edit a file? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `-i` switch is for: edit-in-place:

```
sed -i -e "s/ foo//" ./test
```

The `-i` switch is documented in `man sed`:

> **-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]**
>          edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)

For GNU `sed` (linux), no back-up is created when the suffix is omitted.  For other versions of `sed`, it might be mandatory to supply a backup suffix.

Answer (score 1):

**Empty file**

Shell opens the file `test` for writing -> clearing all its previous contents.

**How to edit same file**

Solution 1:- inline change

```
sed -i.bk "s/ foo//" ./test
```

Solution 2:- use intermediate file (manual version of previous cmd)

```
sed -e "s/ foo//" ./test > test.bk && mv test.bk test
```

Answer (score 1):

Sed is a [s]tream [ed]itor, not a text editor. Using the '-i' parameter is not POSIX, plus it adds the overhead of creating a temporary file before replacing the original file.

If you want to edit your files truly in place, you should use ed/ex instead.

```
ex -sc '%s/ foo//g|xit' ./test
```

See the manual pages sed(1p), ed(1p) and ex(1p).